# Pandas subtract columns with groupby and mask

Tags: pandas, group-by

For groups under one "SN", I would like to subtract three performance indicators for each group. One group boundaries are the serial number SN and sequential Boolean True values in mask. (So multiple True sequances can exist under one SN).

The first indicator I want is, Csub that subtracts between the first and last values of each group in column 'C'. Second, Bmean, is the mean of each group in column 'B'.

For example:

```
In:

df = pd.DataFrame({"SN" : ["66", "66", "66", "77", "77", "77", "77", "77"], "B" : [-2, -1, -2, 3, 1, -1, 1, 1], "C" : [1, 2, 3, 15, 11, 2, 1, 2],
"mask" : [False, False, False, True, True, False, True, True] })

   SN  B   C  mask
0  66 -2   1  False
1  66 -1   2  False
2  66 -2   3  False
3  77  3  15  True
4  77  1  11  True
5  77 -1   2  False
6  77  1   1  True
7  77  1   2  True

Out:

   SN  B   C  mask     Csub Bmean CdivB
0  66 -2   1  False    Nan   Nan  Nan
1  66 -1   2  False    Nan   Nan  Nan
2  66 -2   3  False    Nan   Nan  Nan
3  77  3  15  True     -4    13  -0.3
4  77  1  11  True     -4    13  -0.3
5  77 -1   2  False    Nan   Nan  Nan
6  77  1   1  True     1     1    1 
7  77  1   2  True     1     1    1
```

I cooked up something like this, but it groups by the mask T/F values. It should group by SN and sequential True values, not ALL True values. Further, I cannot figure out how to get a subtraction sqeezed in to this.

```
# Extracting performance values
perf = (df.assign(
    Bmean = df['B'], CdivB = df['C']/df['B']
).groupby(['SN','mask'])
    .agg(dict(Bmean ='mean', CdivB = 'mean'))
    .reset_index(drop=False)
)
```

Comment: i don't understand where you get -4 from for row 3, the first Value of C is 15 and the last True value is 2, so `cSub` should be 13 ?

Comment: A very good point. I reformulated the question. It is not about all Ture values but sequences of True velues (Falses break a True sequence). I also managed to put one more groupby criterion to my suggested answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not pretty, but you can try the following.

First, prepare a 'group_key' column in order to group by consecutive True values in 'mask':

```
# Select the rows where 'mask' is True preceded by False.
first_true = df.loc[
    (df['mask'] == True)
    & (df['mask'].shift(fill_value=False) == False) 
]

# Add the column.
df['group_key'] = pd.Series()

# Each row in first_true gets assigned a different 'group_key' value.
df.loc[first_true.index, 'group_key'] = range(len(first_true))

# Forward fill 'group_key' on mask.
df.loc[df['mask'], 'group_key'] = df.loc[df['mask'], 'group_key'].ffill()
```

Then we can group by 'SN' and 'group_key' and compute and assign the indicator values.

```
# Group by 'SN' and 'group_key'.
gdf = df.groupby(by=['SN', 'group_key'], as_index=False)

# Compute indicator values
indicators = pd.DataFrame(gdf.nth(0)) # pd.DataFrame used here to avoid a SettingwithCopyWarning.
indicators['Csub'] = gdf.nth(0)['C'].array - gdf.nth(-1)['C'].array
indicators['Bmean'] = gdf.mean()['B'].array

# Write values to original dataframe
df = df.join(indicators.reindex(columns=['Csub', 'Bmean']))

# Forward fill the indicator values
df.loc[df['mask'], ['Csub', 'Bmean']] = df.loc[df['mask'], ['Csub', 'Bmean']].ffill()

# Drop 'group_key' column
df = df.drop(columns=['group_key'])
```

I excluded 'CdivB' since I couldn't understand what it's value should be.

Comment: This is very pretty in my eyes! Works for the grouping and indicator problem that I have.

Comment: Unfortunately I was a bit hasty. THe solution brekas if the data series goes over two different SNs: df = pd.DataFrame({"SN" : ["66", "66", "66", "77", "77", "77", "77", "77"], "B" : [-2, 1, 2, 3, 1, -1, 1, 1], "C" : [1, 2, 3, 15, 11, 2, 1, 2],
"mask" : [False, True, True, True, True, False, True, True] }) -> odd output.

Comment: When I tested for this case the code behaved as expected. Perhaps you meant: first group by consecutive True values in 'mask' and then by 'SN' (note that order is important here). Try changing `['SN', 'group_key']` to `['group_key', 'SN']` on the groupby and see if that's what you need.

Comment: Feliz Navidad! You are absolutely correct. I carefully went through the meaning of the code and it works perfectly. (This is the 2nd week of Pandas programming for me, so little bit confusing).

Comment: Feliz navidad! Sweet! Good luck.